# Nice way of factory method pattern with inheritance

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

Suppose I have following class hierarchy:

```
class abstract Parent{}

class FirstChild extends Parent {}

class SecondChild extends Parent {}
```

And I'd like to create DTO objects from each child:

```
class abstract ParentDTO {}

class FirstChildDTO extends ParentDTO{}

class SecondChildDTO extends ParentDTO{}
```

I think I need a factory method something like this:

```
ParentDTO createFrom(Parent source);
```

Is there any *nice* way to do this in Java without `instanceof` checks and if/else statements?

**EDIT**:
This factory method does not work:

```
public ParentDTO create(Parent source)
{
    return _create(source);
}

private FirstChildDTO _create(FirstChild source)
{
    return new FirstDTO();
}

private SecondChildDTO _create(SecondChild source)
{
    return new SecondDTO();
}

private ParentDTO _create(Parent source)
{
    return new ParentDTO();
}
```

It only generates `ParentDTO`s and here is why:

```
Parent p = new FirstChild();
System.out.println(factory.create(p));  //ParentDTO

FirstChild f = new FirstChild();
System.out.println(factory.create(f));  //FirstChildDTO
```

Comment: In Java, [favor composition over inheritance](https://books.google.be/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81) for value objects. It creates problems and headaches you don't want/need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using a factory for DTO creation you can use simple method overloading. Example follows:

```
public class Factory {

    public ParentDTO createDTO(Parent parent) {
        return new ParentDTO();
    }
    public FirstChildDTO createDTO(FirstChild firstChild) {
        return new FirstChildDTO();
    }
    public SecondChildDTO createDTO(SecondChild SecondChild) {
        return new SecondChildDTO();
    }
}

public class Parent {
}

public class FirstChild extends Parent {
}

public class SecondChild extends Parent {
}

public class ParentDTO {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class FirstChildDTO extends ParentDTO {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class SecondChildDTO extends ParentDTO {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        ParentDTO parentDTO = factory.createDTO(new Parent());
        System.out.println(parentDTO);
        FirstChildDTO firstChildDTO = factory.createDTO(new FirstChild());
        System.out.println(firstChildDTO);
        SecondChildDTO secondChildDTO = factory.createDTO(new SecondChild());
        System.out.println(secondChildDTO);
    }
}
```

Running the App as Java application in my IDE outputs:

ParentDTO
FirstChildDTO
SecondChildDTO

Comment: It's the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work. Only `ParentDTO` instances are created in this way.

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to work for me. I'm going to edit my answer to provide you the details. Can you please try it on your machine?

Comment: Yes this works fine. I was trying another case, I'm updating the question with it.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a complex question. I'd resolve this in few steps.

1. `Parent` class should have some kind of interface that would allow your factory to recognize, what data should your `DTO` object contain, like this (in PHP language):

   ```
   class Parent
   {    
        abstract function getDataFields();    
   }

   class FirstChild extends Parent
   {    
        function getDataFields()
        {
            return ['id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name, 'email' => $this->email];   
        }    
   } 

   class SecondChild extends Parent
   {    
       function getDataFields()
       {
           return ['id' => $this->id, 'brand' => $this->brand, 'model' => $this->model];
       }    
   }
   ```
2. Now, you only need a single factory, AND i would use a single class for DTO too, since you know what subclass of `Parent`

   ```
   class DTOFactory
   {
       function createFromParent(Parent $parent)
       {
           return new DTO($parent);
       }   
   }

   class DTO
   {
       private $fields = [];

       function __construct(Parent $parent)
       {
            foreach ($parent->getDataFields() as $field => $value) {
                $this->fields[$field] = $value
            } 
       }

       function __get($field)
       {
            return $this->fields[$field];
       }
   }
   ```

Of course, there are a lot of ways to make DTO's in various languages, i can't cover this in detail, that's up to you.

3. You `could` do your factory method static, but if you want to avoid that, you have to use `Dependency Injection` of some sorts:

   ```
   class MyController
   {
       private $dtoFactory;

       function __construct(DTOFactory $factory)
       {
           $this->dtoFactory = $factory;
       }

       function returnDTOAction()
       {
           $object = new FirstChild(); // or some other way to get your child;
           return $this->factory->createFromParent($object);
       }
   }

   class DIContainer
   {
       private $instances = [];

       function get($className)
       {
           if (!is_object($this->instances[$className]) {
               $this->instances[$className] = new $className;                
           }

           return $this->instances[$className] = new $className;       
       }
   }

   $container = new DIContainer;

   $controller = new MyController($container->get('DTOFactory'));
   ```

This is a very simple example of `DI Container`, better examples have automatic dependency resolution, so you simply call them like `$container->get('MyController');` and get a class with automatically resolved dependencies, but i won't go into further detail on this, since their implementation is heavily language-dependent, and i only stuck with a basic one.

Anyways, hope this helps. If you need some clarifications - feel free to comment.

Comment: Nicely done in dynamic languages. Maybe I should restrict the question to Java :)

Comment: I'm not that experienced in Java, but i guess you use `HashMap` as your `DTO` field key-value storage, and that's it. And, as far as i know, Java has A LOT of DI-Containers implementations, so that won't be a problem too.

Comment: @Eternal1 Java is strictly typed and HashMap was not really introduced as a replacement for value objects. While your suggestion could be implemented easily in Java, it should ideally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can code the factory method directly into the model class and utilize Java's [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) to return the correct type of DTO, for example:

```
public class Parent {

    public ParentDTO createDTO() {
        return new ParentDTO();
    }
}


public class FirstChild extends Parent {

    @Override
    public FirstChildDTO createDTO() {
        return new FirstChildDTO();
    }
}


public class SecondChild extends Parent {

    @Override
    public SecondChildDTO createDTO() {
        return new SecondChildDTO();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the idea is de-coupling model and DTOs.

Comment: No problem. You should pick the design that suits you best. Please also check my other answer.