# User Roles as Marker Interface on DTOs

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have something like this

```
//A marker Interface
public interface User {
}

//2 DTO Classes
public class Administrator implements User{
//getters and setters
}

public class OperativeUser implements User{
//getters and setters
}

//A generic interface
public interface UserService<T extends User>{
    public void createUser(T user);    
}
//Two concrete clases
public class AdministratorService implements UserService<Administrator>{
    public void createUser(Administrator user){
       //specific stuff for an administrator
    }    
}
public class OperativeUserService implements UserService<OperativeUser>{
    public void createUser(OperativeUser user){
       //specific stuff for an operative user
    }    
}
```

All this because if I write a simple UserDTO then in order to differenciate them I will end with an spagetti code like if is administrator do this and if is operative user do that, so a need to classify the users of my system as a common interface but no common behavior

So my questions are

1.-There is a better way to achieve this kind of hierarchy without inheritance(extends) if yes could you give me some guidence?

2.- Is a good use of markers interfaces the way I did or I misunderstood?

This is base on the following questions and answers

[Nice way of factory method pattern with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025483/nice-way-of-factory-method-pattern-with-inheritance)

[Interfaces for DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331067/interfaces-for-dtos)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is opinion based.

I'm sharing my views on it.

What you have is a slightly modified version of an [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). The real question here is, do you need all this?

If `Administrator` and `OperativeUser` are value objects (as indicated in your question) and will have different properties, why bother creating a super type (`User`) for them? You will anyways end up doing `instance of` checks somewhere in your code. In this case your `UserService` is simplified to something like this (yes plain old method overloading!)

```
public class UserService {
    public void createUser(Administrator administrator) {
        //create an admin
    }

    public void createUser(OperativeUser operativeUser) {
        //create an operative user
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you do have common methods for your `Adminstrator` and `OperativeUser` , then they should be declared in the `User` interface which now is no longer a marker interface.

So to answer your questions

> 1.-There is a better way to achieve this kind of hierarchy without inheritance(extends) if yes could you give me some guidence?

Answer: Don't use inheritance unless you need it.

> 2.- Is a good use of markers interfaces the way I did or I misunderstood?

Answer: I don't feel this usage is correct. The reason I say so is because in order to create, let's say and `Administrator` as per your code sample, I would have to write something like this

```
new AdministratorService().createUser(new Administrator());
```

The same can be achieved if you simply overload the methods as I explained above with less code and less hierarchy!

More on why marker interfaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995198/what-is-the-use-of-marker-interfaces-in-java).

Comment: Hi Pravin, the thing about the type user is because in that way I just can do the following `@Inject @User(Type="Administrator") User administrator;` and  `@Inject @User(Type="OperativeUser")User operative;` so If a new user added nothing that already have relase need to be edited and violate Open Close Principle

Comment: @jjam But will you be able to use a `User` as an `Administrator` elsewhere without casting it?. Its not about the convenience of instantiation/injection but about being able to use a `User` instance polymorphically. Besides, I'm not sure if I understand how this violates open/close principle.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not realize that my code will work just fine in my particular case but  in other part of my project when I need to use a particular user I need to check if that particular object is instance of an x object as you mention early and it will end with the spaghetti code that I trying to avoid at first, so this solve my particular problem and answer my specific questions, thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Adminstrator vs other User is really an issue of roles/permissions. And in a mature system, you might have more than just two..

I would suggest you start by adding "roles" & a convenience `isAdministrator()` check:

```
public class User {
    public String getName();

    public Set<String> getRoles();
    public boolean isAdministrator();
}
```

I have proposed Roles as `Set<String>';  this will be make it easy to check roles using string constants. (The alternative could be`Set`).

This provides a concise way of checking for administrator role, enables User to be a concrete class & removes the need for separate types for "plain" User and Administrator, and enables your role system to be refined & expanded in future.

Bigger systems than this take the Role structure further: they model "Permissions" and allow flexible assignment of Users -> Roles and Roles -> Permissions. However, that degree of sophistication is beyond your current problem.